# Rotate text out of control

Tags: css, rotatetransform

I rotate a h4-tag like this:

```
.c_kolumnen h4{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:gray;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    text-align: center;

}
```

and the parent-container of it has these values:

```
.c_kolumnen {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 8.33333%;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-rendering: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now I do have 2 problems with the rotated text:

- a. It's 2-lined even though the value needs way less space then it
  has.
- b. It doesn't horizontally (I am not sure if horizontally is the
  right name for it, because I obviously twisted things) align at all.

See the screenshot therefore, please.
[image: Screenshot of the container and the h4-element]

What did I do wrong there?

Comment: Try adding `transform-origin: 0 0;`.

Comment: Your width is making it linebreak

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the origin @putvande / 0 0 doesn't do the job, but it points me in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveBurns I don't get, which width you mean, and how it affects the linebreaks? The container has 8.x% of the parents' container and the h4-element itself doesn't inherit, because I already tried with a width to the h4-element itself

Comment: When I changed `width: 8.33333%;` it worked in Chrome, try it out for yourself :)